# Generate a grammar using a regex pattern in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, grammar

I would like to use regex pattern not to know if an existing string matches that pattern, but instead to generate all possible values that match that pattern. For example with the pattern \d\d\d it should generate words including "000" "001" "002" etc up to "999". These can be made available in any format, an array or a comma separated list etc. How can this be done in Perl? Is this a built in feature or will a module be required?

It doesn't need to handle every possible pattern, only generating a language for patterns of digits or letters of the alphabet would be sufficient.

Comment: What order should infinite series such as `\d+\w+` be iterated?

Comment: The pattern I would use would be finite, like the example provided - just any three digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For very simple cases like you mentioned in the comment—just three digits—that's just a small recursion, like here (processing only `\d`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %results = ();    # global variables are evil

sub generate {
    my ($pattern) = @_;
    if ( $pattern =~ /^(.*)\\d(.*)$/ ) {
        my ( $before, $after ) = ( $1, $2 );
        for my $digit ( 0 .. 9 ) {
            generate( $before . $digit . $after );
        }
    } else {
        $results{$pattern} = 1;
    }
}

generate('a\db\dc');
print join( "\n", sort keys %results ), "\n";
```

This recursive approach does not actually depend on the particular language and can be implemented in the same way in any programming language, nothing Perl-specific here.

For more complicated expressions use `Regexp::Genex` as suggested by @daxim.

Answer (score 5):

The [Regexp::Genex](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Genex) and [String::Random](http://p3rl.org/String::Random) modules expands regexes into strings that match the pattern.